# Maven - how to unpack a jar and build the war files using unpacked files(class)

Tags: maven, jar, war, ear

Is there any way to unpack a dependent jar and include the required class files from it to a war file.

I have two modules, namely module-A and module-B.
Module-A packaged as jar, and module-B packaged as war.
Module-A is added as dependency in module-B.

Now i get module-A jar file inside module-B. I need to include the class files, available inside Module-A jar file, into a specific folder in my war.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but it sounds like you simply need to add a dependency? Apart from that jar files will not being unpackaged they will be kept as jar and put into war file /WEB-INF/lib directory ?

Comment: Hi khmarbaise,

Thank you for your reply.

I was using a service module and a persistence module before. And i kept the persistence module(jar) as a dependency to the service module(war). The service module contains the rest end point classes.
At that time the war structure was as given below,

Comment: some.war\WEB-INF\classes\ - under this all the rest entry classes.
some.war\WEB-INF\lib\ - under this all the dependency jar, including my persistence module.
Note: There is no web.xml since i am using wildfly-11.

Comment: When i created another module for building the war file, i kept the dependency for service module and persistence module inside new war module. Now i am getting the rest entry classes as a jar and it is kept under WEB-INF\lib\ folder. Upon deploying it is failing with error 404. So i think all the classes related to rest should be placed under some.war\WEB-INF\classes\ folder.
In order to do this i should unpack the dependent jar(service.jar) and keep the same under some.war\WEB-INF\classes\ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,

It is as simple as to change the packaging of the new module to ear. Then the existing war module keep as it is.

Put all the sub module dependency in ear module, make sure to add war tag for your war module dependency.

I was not having good understanding about ear packaging.

Any better idea would be appreciated, thanks in advance.